# Is this a valid proof concerning Mersenne Primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, formal-proofs, mersenne-numbers

I am very new to proofs, and I learned that for $2^c-1=n$, if $c$ is composite, then $n$ is composite.  I recently learned about proofs by contradiction, so here is my attempt at proving this statement.  Please let me know if it is valid/invalid and how it can be improved.

## Proof by contradiction

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ where $a,b>1$, and $p$ be a prime number.

Assume that $2^{ab}-1=p$ is possible.  There are two possibilities: $ab$ is even or odd.

**If $ab$ is even:**

Then $2^{ab}-1$ can be factored as a difference of squares: $(2^{\frac{ab}{2}}+1)(2^{\frac{ab}{2}}-1)=p$

Since $\frac{ab}{2}$ is always an integer, then both factors of $p$ are integers that are not $1$, so $p$ cannot be prime.

**If $ab$ is odd:**

Then $2^{ab}-1=p \Rightarrow 2^{ab+1}-2=2p \Rightarrow 2^{ab+1}-1=2p+1$

Now, since $ab+1$is even, $2^{ab+1}-1$ can be factored as a difference of squares.

$(2^{\frac{ab+1}{2}}+1)(2^{\frac{ab+1}{2}}-1)=2p+1$

Isolate $p$, and we get:

$\frac{(2^{\frac{ab+1}{2}}+1)(2^{\frac{ab+1}{2}}-1)-1}{2}=p$

Both the numerator and denominator are clearly integers, so $p$ cannot be prime.

$Q.E.D$

Again, please let me know if this is a valid proof.  Thank you.

Comment: "Both the numerator and denominator are clearly integers, so p cannot be prime." Does not follow. You haven't proved that the numerator isn't just 2 times a prime.

Comment: In your second part you have to deal with the numerator being even. Because for instance $6/2=3$ is prime even though the numerator and denominator of $6/2$ are both integers.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Do you know how I might be able to resolve this?

Comment: Hint for an alternate proof: $2^{ab} - 1 = (2^a)^b - 1^b$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog is the fact that you can factor $a^n - b^n$ show that it cannot be prime?

Comment: You are familiar with the difference of squares formula: did you know there is also a difference of $n$-th powers formula for any $n >1$?

Comment: @RobBland I just discovered it after looking at eyeballfrog's comment.  Does the fact that you can factor $(2^a)^b - 1^b$ prove that it cannot be prime?

Comment: You have to still argue that each of the factors is $>1$, but yes

Comment: @RobBland Well, if $x=2^a$ and $y=1$, then $(x-y) > 1$ for all $a > 1$.  And for the other factor, $(x^{b-1} + x^{b-2}y+ ... + y^{b-1})$, since $b > 1$ and is an integer, and $x > 1$ and is an integer, and $y=1$ in this case, this factor must also be greater than 1.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: @RobBland thank you so much.  You’ve helped me a lot.